# Record audio with getUserMedia in safari

Tags: safari, getusermedia

I'm trying to record audio with ***getUserMedia***. It works in chrome but it does not work in safari. My safari version is 13. I think safari does not support it. I'm using `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` to check if browser support it or not. Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Safari doesn't yet have  MediaRecorder web api. Is  that where things fail for you?

Comment: I can now use the MediaRecorder by enabling it in Develop > Experimental features. I can record the audio but when I try to pause it, it returns undefined. I think MediaRecord does not support pause in safari.

Comment: You might consider using the Safari technology preview, and putting in a bug report for stuff that works in Chrome but not Safari. The Safari team are in the process of trying to re-invent the wheel for this media stuff. So far, they've re-invented the flat tire.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've sent the feedback to add pause and resume functions for MediaRecorder API